# Unit testing DevForce EntityManager.InvokeServerMethod

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, devforce

In a WPF application I have a view model that retrieves data from the server using a DevForce Entity Manager `InvokeServerMethod` call. I would like to unit test by view model.

Using Moq, I mocked the `IEntityManagerProvider` and setup the `InvokeServerMethod`.

```
var mockManager = new Mock<MyEntities>(MockBehavior.Loose, false, null, 
    EntityServiceOption.UseDefaultService, "Fake");

var mockProvider = new Mock<IEntityManagerProvider<MyEntities>>(MockBehaviour.Loose);

mockProvider.Setup(m => m.Manager).Returns(mockManager.Object);

mockManager
    .Setup(m => m.InvokeServerMethod(It.IsAny<ServerMethodDelegate>())
    .Returns(new List<int>());
```

But when I run the test, I get

> "Invalid setup on non-virtual member".

Next, I went into my `IEntityManagerProvider` interface and created this method

```
object MockableServerMethod(ServerMethodDelegate method, params object[] 
    parameters);
```

Then I implemented this new method

```
public object MockableServerMethod(ServerMethodDelegate method, params 
    object[] parameters)
{
    return Manager.InvokeServerMethod(method, params);
}
```

This allows me to mock the server call, but requires me to change the production code, which I really shouldn't have to do.

What is the correct way to write a unit test when the method being tested calls `InvokeServerMethod()`?

Comment: Is `InvokeServerMethod` a virtual member? Show the definition of the respective mocks.

Comment: Sorry, my question should have been worded better.

InvokeServerMethod() is a method of the IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager. I am creating a mock of that object and passing it to the IEntityManagerProvider. (See the initial setup). The non-virtual method is a member of this class, which I don't control.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a cleaner solution, although it still requires a change to production code.

MyEntities is a partial class that inherits from IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityManager. Therefore, I was able to add the following code to MyEntities

```
public virtual async Task<object>ExecuteServerMethodAsync(
    ServerMethodDelegate method, params object[] parameters)
{
    return await InvokeServerMethodAsync(method, parameters);
}
```

Now, my production code calls Execute... rather than Invoke... and the Execute method is mockable.

Dave